# How to associate an Sequence to a column in PowerDesigner?

Tags: postgresql, powerdesigner

I'm using powerdesigner 15.2 to model an postgresql database, but i can't associate sequences with PKs...
read on internet that:

"To associate the sequence with the column, double-click the column entry. Then, in the General tab, specify the name of the sequence."

but i already did this...

[image: Sequence associated]

the problem is that when i generate database, the sequences are simply created, but not associated with the column...

```
create sequence SQ_CARGO;

create table CARGO (
   ID                   INT4                 not null,
   NOME                 VARCHAR(20)          not null,
   ROLE                 VARCHAR(100)         not null,
   constraint PK_CARGO primary key (ID)
);
```

Current DBMS in Powerdesigner: PostgreSQL 8 (but i'm using postgresql 9.4)

anyone knows how to do this? or else i will be forced to set this manually for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE cargo ALTER COLUMN ID SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('SQ_CARGO'::regclass);
```

Comment: i forgot to comment that Postgres 8 is the lastest Postgresql option in my Powerdesigner 15.2, but i'm using postgresql 9.4 in my pc

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, i wrote this code and replace, in DBMS Properties, the value:(Script->Objects->Table->Create).

```
create [%Temporary% ]table [%QUALIFIER%]%TABLE% ( %TABLDEFN% )
[%OPTIONS%];

.foreach_item(Columns)
    .if (%COLNNO%==1) && (%Primary% == TRUE) && (%SQNC% != "") 
        ALTER TABLE [%QUALIFIER%]%TABLE% ALTER COLUMN %COLUMN% SET DEFAULT
nextval('[%QUALIFIER%]%SQNC%')
    .endif 
.next(\n)
```

Taking advantage, I have a problem when it generated the creation of code SEQUENCE.

I can not get the code to be generated with the OWNER of the prefix object.

ex:
The code is generated as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TABLE_SQ;
```

And it should be generated like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OWNER.TABLE_SQ;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gilvan: You must select the owner on the "New Sequence" window, on the "Owner" combobox.

Answer (score 1):

was a bug!
download a new version and works fine.